# Parsing SVG paths in R

Tags: r, node.js, svg

I'm trying to crack an R workflow for parsing SVG paths, using [this file](https://visionscarto.net/public/fonds-de-cartes-en/visionscarto-bertin1953.svg) on [this webpage](https://visionscarto.net/base-maps). I'm encountering artifacts in the positioning of resulting polygons:

[image]

Some of the countries do not align with their neighbours - e.g. US/Canada, US/Mexico, Russia/Asian neighbours. Since the effect hits the countries with more complex polygons it seems likely to be a problem to do with cumulative summing, but I'm unclear where the problem lies in my workflow, which is:

1. parse raw SVG as XML, and extract all the SVG path strings
2. parse individual path strings with `nodejs`'s [svg-path-parser module](https://github.com/hughsk/svg-path-parser)
3. process the resulting data.frames (which combine absolute and relative coordinates) into all absolute coordinates

I reproduce the full workflow here using R (for US/Canada), with an external call to nodejs:

```
require(dplyr)
require(purrr)
require(stringr)
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(rvest)
require(xml2)
require(jsonlite)

# Get and parse the SVG
doc = read_xml('https://visionscarto.net/public/fonds-de-cartes-en/visionscarto-bertin1953.svg')

countries = doc %>% html_nodes('.country')
names(countries) = html_attr(countries, 'id')
cdi = str_which(names(countries), 'CIV') # unicode in Cote d'Ivoire breaks the code
countries = countries[-cdi]

# Extract SVG paths and parse with node's svg-path-parser module.
# If you don't have node you can use this instead (note this step might be the problem):
# d = read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/b7353a7a8a480209b31418c806cb1c9e/raw/6d3ba2a62f6e8667eef15e29a5893d9d795e8bb1/bertin_svg.csv')

d = imap_dfr(countries, ~{
  message(.y)
  svg_path = xml_find_all(.x, paste0("//*[@id='", .y, "']/d1:path")) %>% html_attr('d')
  node_call = paste0("node -e \"var parseSVG = require('svg-path-parser'); var d='", svg_path,
                     "'; console.log(JSON.stringify(parseSVG(d)));\"")
  system(node_call, intern = T) %>% fromJSON %>% mutate(country = .y)
}) %>% as_data_frame()


# some initial processing
d1 = d %>% filter(country %in% c('USA United States','CAN Canada')) %>%
  mutate(x = replace_na(x, 0), y = replace_na(y, 0), # NAs need replacing
         relative = replace_na(relative, FALSE),
         grp = (command == 'closepath') %>% cumsum)  # polygon grouping variable

# new object to loop through
d2 = d1 %>% mutate(x_adj = x, y_adj = y) %>% filter(command != 'closepath')

# loop through and change relative coords to absolute
for(i in 2:nrow(d2)){
  if(d2$relative[i]){ # cumulative sum where coords are relative
    d2$x_adj[i] = d2$x_adj[i-1] + d2$x_adj[i]
    d2$y_adj[i] = d2$y_adj[i-1] + d2$y_adj[i]
  } else{ # code M/L require no alteration
    if(d2$code[i] == 'V') d2$x_adj[i] = d2$x_adj[i-1] # absolute vertical transform inherits previous x
    if(d2$code[i] == 'H') d2$y_adj[i] = d2$y_adj[i-1] # absolute holrizontal transform etc
  }
}

# plot result
d2 %>% ggplot(aes(x_adj, -y_adj, group = paste(country, grp))) +
  geom_polygon(fill='white', col='black', size=.3) +
  coord_equal() + guides(fill=F)
```

[image]

Any assistance appreciated.  The SVG path syntax is specified at [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html) and summarised more concisely [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/).

---

**Edit (response to @ccprog)**

Here is data returned from `svg-path-parser` for the `H` command sequence:

```
  code  command                 x      y relative country   
  <chr> <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>    <chr>     
1 l     lineto              -0.91  -0.6  TRUE     CAN Canada
2 l     lineto              -0.92  -0.59 TRUE     CAN Canada
3 H     horizontal lineto  189.    NA    NA       CAN Canada
4 l     lineto              -1.03   0.02 TRUE     CAN Canada
5 l     lineto              -0.74  -0.07 TRUE     CAN Canada
```

Here is what `d2` looks like for same sequence after the loop:

```
  code  command                 x     y relative country      grp x_adj y_adj
  <chr> <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    <chr>      <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 l     lineto              -0.91 -0.6  TRUE     CAN Canada    20  199.  143.
2 l     lineto              -0.92 -0.59 TRUE     CAN Canada    20  198.  143.
3 H     horizontal lineto  189.    0    FALSE    CAN Canada    20  189.  143.
4 l     lineto              -1.03  0.02 TRUE     CAN Canada    20  188.  143.
5 l     lineto              -0.74 -0.07 TRUE     CAN Canada    20  187.  143.
```

Does this not look ok?. When I look at raw values for y_adj for `H` and previous rows they are identical `142.56`.

---

### Edit 2: working solution, thanks to @ccprog

```
d = imap_dfr(countries, ~{
  message(.y)
  svg_path = xml_find_all(.x, paste0("//*[@id='", .y, "']/d1:path")) %>% html_attr('d')
  node_call = paste0("node -e \"var parseSVG = require('svg-path-parser'); var d='", svg_path,
                     "'; console.log(JSON.stringify(parseSVG.makeAbsolute(parseSVG(d))));\"")
  system(node_call, intern = T) %>% fromJSON %>% mutate(country = .y)
}) %>% as_data_frame() %>% 
  mutate(grp = (command == 'moveto') %>% cumsum)

d %>% ggplot(aes(x, -y, group = grp, fill=country)) +
  geom_polygon(col='black', size=.3, alpha=.5) +
  coord_equal() + guides(fill=F)
```

Comment: I've also submitted this to the [svg-path-parser](https://github.com/hughsk/svg-path-parser/issues/16) module on github

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but to me it looks like you divide the path into groups by looking for `closepath` commands, and then take the first `moveto` in each group as starting point to cumulate positions from for the conversion to absolute. Two sources of errors are:1.  `moveto` commands, apart from the first one, can also be relative (to the last coordinate of the previous group). 2. Groups must not be closed with a `closepath` command. Searching for the opening `moveto` would be more reliable.

Comment: Hi @ccprog. I do use `closepath` to create variable `grp` (that identifies unique polygons), but it does not have any role in parsing the actual coordinates. In fact I just use the SVG `relative` field which as I understand specifies when coordinates are relative or absolute.  With absolute codes you have to also account for `H`/`V` commands, which inherit the inactive coordinate from the previous point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your rendering of Canada, especially the southern coast of the Hudson sound. There is a very obvious error. Sieveing through the path data, I found the following sequence in the original data:

```
h-2.28l-.91-.6-.92-.59H188.65l-1.03.02-.74-.07-.75-.07-.74-.07-.74-.06.88 1.09
```

I've loaded your rendering result into Inkscape, and drawn the relevant part of the path on top, the arrow marking the segment drawn by the absolute H command. (The z command has been removed, that is the reason for the missing segment.) It is obvious that somewhere in there a segment is too long.

[image]

It turns out the absolute `H` *corrects* the previous (horizontal) error. Look at the preceding point: it is `198., 143.`, but it should be `191.76,146.07`. The vertical error remains at about -3.6.

I've made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgdMMz) that overlays the original path data with your rendering as precisely as possible. The path data have been divided into the (single-polygon) groups and converted to absolute by Inkscape. Unfortunately, the program cannot convert them to polygon primitives, so there are still V and H commands in there.

It shows this:

- The starting point of the path matches.
- The point described by the absolute H command has a matching horizontal value, but not vertical. (It is the only absolute command in the whole path.)
- Every path group (polygon) seems to be consistent in itself, but apart from `group0` they all are removed from their intended place.

I've made some visual measurements of that deviation (error ~0.05), and they ultimately give the clue:

```
group01: 0.44,-0.73
group02: 0.84,-1.12
group03: 2.04,-1.44
group04: 2.94,-1.73
group05: 2.60,-1.86
group06: 3.14,-2.38
group07: 3.68,-2.54
group08: 4.03,-3.35
group09: 4.87,-2.97
group10: 6.08,-3.50 (begin)
group10: 0.00,-3.53 (end)
group11: 1.08,-1.95
group12: 2.05,-2.45
group13: 2.89,-2.84
group14: 3.64,-3.67
group15: 4.48,-3.44
group16: 4.04,-3.99
group17: 4.32,-3.08
group18: 4.75,-2.75
group19: 5.72,-2.95
group20: 5.40,-3.11
group21: 6.02,-2.95
group22: 6.63,-4.14
group23: 6.85,-5.00
group24: 7.14,-4.86
group25: 7.72,-4.39
group26: 8.65,-4.75
group27: 9.49,-4.39
group28: 10.20,-4.44
group29: 11.13,-4.58
```

You are removing the `closepath` commands, and then compute the first point of the next group relative to the last explicit point of the last group. But `closepath` actually moves the ccurrent point: back to the position of the last `moveto` command. These may, but need not be identical.

I can't give you a ready script in R, but what you need to do is this: at the beginning of a new group, cache the position of the first point. At the beginning of the next group, compute the new first point relative to that cached point.

Comment: Thanks for help ccprog. Good to focus on specifics like this. So it's true I set the NA values for `y` variable of `H` commands to zero. But later I override that with `if(d2$code[i] == 'H') d2$y_adj[i] = d2$y_adj[i-1]` - basically inherit previous `y` value.  I include relevant data.frame sections for `d` and `d2` - added to question.

Comment: I understand, but I am absolutely sure the culprit is that absolute H command. I've added a screenshot to prove my point.

Comment: No, the absolute H _corrects_ the (horizontal) error. Look at the preceding point: it is `198., 143.`,  but it should be `191.76,146.07`. The vertical error remains. If, in addition, I account for the vertical error and move your rendering up by dy=-3.6, the very first point of the path data matches. As far as I can judge, all other path groups are internally consistent, but the further down in the path data they are, the more they are off to the bottom left.

Comment: This is going to take some thinking. Will come back shortly.

Comment: I've made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WgdMMz) that overlays the original path data with your rendering as precisely as possible. The path data have been divided into the (single-polygon) groups and converted to absolute by Inkscape. Unfortunately, the program cannot convert them to polygon primitives, so there are still V and H commands in there.

Comment: I've run a higher resolution plot which should help to clarify the precise nature of the anomaly - https://imgur.com/a/nsyDOnU

Comment: Now I've found the error. This is the definite answer.

Comment: You. Little. Ripper. This has to be it! Going to complicate my code but will get on it.

Comment: ...and now I am scrolling down [this page](https://github.com/hughsk/svg-path-parser#absolute-path-commands) and see that the parser has an option for converting paths to absolute commands. That should make your live easier.

Comment: Ho ho, quite an oversight! OK that simplifies everything considerably. The node console.log call becomes `console.log(JSON.stringify(parseSVG.makeAbsolute(parseSVG(d))))` and I group with `mutate(grp = (command == 'moveto') %>% cumsum)`.

Comment: You've been massively helpful ccprog - thank you. It's been fun.

Comment: And this is useful to me too, because although I don't need to draw Canada, I do need to parse SVG paths in R. I've just learnt something.